# Add a condition to one of the scores output in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, text-mining

I am outputting some readability scores as a table using Rmarkdown and was wondering if there any way I could add a condition to one of the rows saying "if the score is greater or equal to 14 then output the colour as red otherwise green"
The following is the code to generate the sample data:

```
FGL <- 16
    Readability_score <- data.frame(Type = c("SMOG","Flesch Reading Ease","Flesch-Kincaid Grade Level", 
                                         "Gunning Fog Score", "Automated Readability Index"), 
                                Score = c(17,23,FGL,22, 19))
```

This is the code to output the table in html using Rmarkdown:

```
    kable(Readability_score, "html") %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped", full_width = F, position = "left") %>%
  row_spec(3, bold = T, color = "white", background = "grey")
```

I would like the 3rd element of the data frame to be highlighted in red (Flesch-Kincaid Grade level, 16) if the score is greater than 14. 
So far I tried using `cell_spec()` with the below code but could not get it to work

```
FGL <- 16

Readability_score <- data.frame(Type = c("SMOG","Flesch Reading Ease","Flesch-Kincaid Grade Level", 
                                         "Gunning Fog Score", "Automated Readability Index"), 
                                Score = c(17,23,cell_spec(FGL, "html", color = ifelse(FGL >= 14, "red", "green")),22, 19))
```

Maybe using `cell_spec()` here is not a good idea. Any other suggestions regarding ways to achieve what I am trying to achieve here or if anyone could point out any mistake in my code - would be really helpful, Thanks.

PS. To run the above code: the following packages would be required

```
library("dplyr")
library("knitr")
library("kableExtra")
```

Comment: hello you can check `kableExtra` https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_html.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to set `escape=F` argument in the kable function

```
library("dplyr")
library("knitr")
library("kableExtra")

FGL <- 16

Readability_score <- data.frame(Type = c("SMOG",
                                     "Flesch Reading Ease",
                                     "Flesch-Kincaid Grade Level", 
                                     "Gunning Fog Score", 
                                     "Automated Readability Index"), 
                            Score = c(17,23,
                                      cell_spec(FGL, "html", 
                                                      color = ifelse(FGL >= 14, "red", "green")),22, 19))
```

In the below line `escape=F` is added to the code you already wrote

```
kable(Readability_score, "html", escape = F) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped", full_width = F, position = "left")
```

Comment: Thanks @dmail. The initial output was showing the HTML code and I'm guessing escape argument tells the function to ignore the HTML and output the actual value.